# Using multiple placeholders on a page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Currently on my website when a user logs in if their role in their row within the Users table is equal to 0 it will give the user 3 options on options.aspx, however if not it will take them to home.aspx

Now I am trying to just do this on one whole page, so if the user was to be directed to the options page, instead it would take them to the home page where the user would have to click an option amongst the 3, if the user has already selected an option then it would load a different content placeholder.

Is a content placeholder what I need to achieve my idea? If so, wouldn't it be abit too easy to get out of the situation since the client could inspect element and edit the visibility on their side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the Visible="false" property on a server-side control (runat="server") the tag is NOT rendered to the browser. As a result, the client cannot set it as visible. So for example:

`<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" Visible="false">SomeText</asp:PlaceHolder>`

The SomeText will be nowhere to be found in the HTML if the user does View Source. If, however, you do a CSS style on a control such as `style="display:none"` then your concern is 100% valid as the user could just show this.

This same logic hold true for any ASP.NET server-side control. If you set Visible="false" it's never sent to the browser.